# Unable to create record in Community

Tags: community, account, contact, sharing-sets

I have the following objects Contact (looks up to) -> Account, Project, Project Role (looks up to Contact and Project)

A portal user has the following access to the objects:

1. Account (Public Read-Only)
2. Contact (Controlled By Parent)
3. Project (Read-Only)
4. Project Role (Read, Create, Edit)

When I try to create a Project Role record in the community I receive the following error:
[image]

**EDIT:** I'm able to save Project Role when the contact associated with the Project Role record is created by the community user.

What am I missing here? I suspect either Account or Contact is the issue here for the Portal user but I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you use RecordTypes? If so, does the Community Profile have access to the RecordType used in the creation of Project Role? Do you have automation (code or declarative) updating other related objects using `with sharing`?

Comment: No RecordTypes, No Automation at all @TSmith